# Remove all lines that start with a hash from a list

Tags: sed

For a simple example say I have list file which has the following contents

```
cat dog pig
dog hat
cat
clap sing
king
ca
cat hog
plate
plate
one two three
cat
```

I then have a 'pattern' file. With the below content

```
cat 
dog
```

What I would like to happen is a new file is created from the list file but all lines that begin with cat or dog I not copied over.

I have seen a few examples how this can work e.g.

```
sed '/pattern to match/d' ./infile > ./newfile
```

From what I have gathered sed can't handle a 'pattern input file'. Is that a similar program to sed that could achieve what I would like to do? If not could a make a program in python program that reads each line from the 'pattern' file and run the sed command against th list file e.g. multiple passes with seds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tell grep to read its patterns from a file - with the -v (invert) switch that should do what you want

```
fgrep -vf patternfile listfile
```

From `man grep`

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Exactly What I wanted Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this what you wanted or not. I have done this what you wanted by deleting the dog & cat multiple patterns and saved the modified in the new file.  see the code

```
 sed '/cat/d; /dog/d' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

below here along with example in the terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ALT<kbd>+T</kbd>)

```
raja@debian:~/sand$ cat file1.txt
cat dog pig
dog hat
cat
clap sing
king
ca
cat hog
plate
plate
one two three
cat
raja@debian:~/sand$ sed '/cat/d; /dog/d' file1.txt > file2.txt
raja@debian:~/sand$ cat file2.txt
clap sing
king
ca
plate
plate
one two three
raja@debian:~/sand$
```

Comment: I knew about this method. Should of been a bit clearer in the question. The files I am going to run this against contains thousands of patterns thus it is impossible to write each individual out each pattern. This is why I need to use a 'pattern input file'